# How to make a custom url show in discord js bot embed messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using v12.6 of discord js. I am trying to make a embed message which will look something like this .

> Position

> Game Developer
> Location

> Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India
>
> [Apply Now](https://google.com)

The problem is that when I am using setURL(applylink) it is making the url hyperlink on setTitle of the embed. I wish to make a seperate tag which looks like above. This is my code

```
 const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffdf00')
            .setTitle( companyName)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Position', value: jobTitle ,inline:true},
                { name: 'Location', value: location+'\n'},
                { name: 'Experience', value: experienceLevel, inline: true },              
                { name: 'Salary Range', value: CTCRange, inline: true },
               
            )
            .addFields({name: 'Qualifications',value: qualificationRequired+'\n'})
            .setURL(linktoApply)

            const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
            channel.send(embed);
```

here companyName and other tags in value are variables.

Comment: Please consider updating your bot, v12 is now broken

Comment: @Palm i am working on that as well in the meantime. Too much on my plate for now but thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hyperlink syntax for bots. *(this does not work on normal messages, it only works for embeds)*

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .addField('Title', 'Description, [Hyperlink](https://example.com)')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will also update my discord version. thanks for your time!